# Java: error "Can not access LinkedList"

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing a simple Java program to rotate a Linked List, but when trying to compile the Java code through the compiler via: `javac RotateLinkedList.java`, I get the following error in my console:

```
jared@jared-linux:~/Desktop/Code Interviews$ javac RotateLinkedList.java 
./LinkedList.java:9: error: class ListOperations is public, should be declared in a file named ListOperations.java
public class ListOperations{
       ^
RotateLinkedList.java:82: error: cannot access LinkedList
        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        ^
bad source file: ./LinkedList.java
    file does not contain class LinkedList
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

Which is odd as this looks to be that the source code for Java is what is failing? I am compiling against `Java JDK 8` and on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Below is a snippet of the code I am running to create the LinkedList, if that helps:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RotateLinkedList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Crate the linked List
        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        // Adding elements to linked list
        System.out.println("How many elements should be in the binary linked list: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = input.nextInt();
        if((num != null) && (num > 0)) {
            System.out.println("Adding " + num + " elements into the linked list.");
            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                ll.add(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Linked List: " + ll);
        } else { 
            System.out.println("NULL or invalid number inputted. Aborting");
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any feedback! Cheers.

Comment: As a note, compiling other Java programs I have written through the console the same way works just fine. I just seem to have an issue compiling this code that pertains to creating a LinkedList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was an idiot and forgot I had a `LinkedList.java` (which is mostly psuedocode, etc) file in my source folder when compiling, so the compiler wanted to import that file when compiling `RotateLinkedList.java`. Argh! Sorry about that. Appreciate the views / responses, though!

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error message is quite straight forward: The name of your java file is not the same as that of the public class defined in it.

It is one of the basic constructs of Java language that the file name should match exactly with the **publicly** declared class in that java file. Note here that there could be multiple classes in a java file, nevertheless, only one publicly declared class in it!

Just to confirm, try changing the name of your java file to "ListOperations.java" and then compile it.

Comment: The name of the Java file is `RotateLinkedList.java`, the compilation error is about ./LinkedList.java and its attributes. However, I tried what you suggested and that did not work. Same error message upon compilation.